# Trying to login customer after registration, Customer logged in but page refresh destroy session

Tags: customer, ajax, session, customer-session

Here is proper explanation of Issue that I am facing on Magento 1.9.2.4

I have made custom popups to register and login customer, I have put extended `Mage_Customer_AccountController` class from my custom module, and simply register customer and login him after it. not more complex customizations.

But I face one issue, I register and login customer successfully, but after receiving ajax response I refresh browser page, and I found customer is not logged in. I have checked customer status right before `$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));` and I verified customer logged in. but some how browser refresh is not showing customer is logged in.

I tried above code in fresh Magento 1.9.2.4 with sample data and with cache disabled. I face same issue.

I think issue is with session instance. To find out session validation, when I put form_key input in my forms and trying to validate, it fails. key value change in my controller action.

My form html input form_key : `<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="B6cegiWPPdruA83H">`

and I am verifying it using this in controller action method: `Mage::log(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(), null, "popups.log", true);`
I found value is different here: `bH60GsLwgJHT6gyC`

I tried above method to verify session instance, I am not sure why it changes on for ajax requests.

so I think session is not persistent, I log in customer in session, and when I refresh browser page, May be new session is created and I lost customer login.

registered customer with my custom forms, can login with normal Magento login form.

can somebody please help me with this ? I am sure I am missing something, but not sure about that. I can post controller methods which I use to register and login customer.

Answer (score 2):

Mukund,there are few reason,this issue rasied

**like:**

Cookie Domain  and other  cookie related setting is not proper that why it is create issue.So you need to fix it.

1. **Cookie Path:** /
2. **Cookie Domain:** .site.com

Most of cases, i have see that is cookie setting issue.

Or,other way,you can ***check it  is cookie setting or not***. **Delete** all *cookie records* from **core_config_data**

```
delete from core_config_data where path like "%cookie%".
```

Other case,you Accountroller  predispatch event may be create issue. For that case,you can follow this question [AccountController override not working on new Action and doing 302 redirection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76628/accountcontroller-override-not-working-on-new-action-and-doing-302-redirection)

Comment: Thanks Amit, I found your suggested link helpful, actually I got my controller working by applying @Marius solution : http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/76697/2401, I was extending ```Mage_Customer_AccountController``` controller, I just stopped and using ```Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action``` and I copied all my required methods to my custom controller. and all resolved. Still I don't understand why that solution worked. but it is. this solution is also validates session form_key. So, Thanks for your time and help. I also learned proper way to send response from your links.