# Override Account Controller for registration function

Tags: overrides, controllers, frontend, customer-account, register

I have done some changes in user registration like add a field group_id and save its values to DB. Code was done and working successfully but It was in core controller. Now I wantr to put taht controller on local. To do ths I followed some guids and stackoverflow answers but everytinme I am nit able to get the desired output. Please help.
my code is

app/code/local/Dev/Customcustomer/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Dev_Customcustomer>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Dev_Customcustomer>
    </modules>
    <!-- start of override Customer AccountController -->

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                    <customcustomer before="Mage_Customer">Dev_Customcustomer</customcustomer>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <customcustomer>
                    <file>customcustomer.xml</file>
                </customcustomer>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <!-- helper -->
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <customcustomer>
                <class>Dev_Customcustomer_Helper</class>
            </customcustomer>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Account controller
app/code/local/Dev/Customcustomer/controllers/AccountController.php

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Customer').DS."AccountController.php";
class Dev_Customcustomer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController{
    /**
     * Action predispatch
     *
     * Check customer authentication for some actions
     */
    public function preDispatch()
    {

        $action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
        $ExitsopenActions = array(
            'create',
            'login',
            'logoutsuccess',
            'forgotpassword',
            'forgotpasswordpost',
            'resetpassword',
            'resetpasswordpost',
            'confirm',
            'confirmation'
        );
        $newOpenAction=array('vendor','vendorcreate','vendorcreatePost','vendorloginPost');

        $allActions=array_merge($ExitsopenActions,$newOpenAction);

        /* check custom action */
        $Custompattern = '/^(' . implode('|', $newOpenAction) . ')/i';


        if (preg_match($Custompattern, $action)) {
            /* if match then set Current action to create for skip  parent::preDispatch(); */
            $this->getRequest()->setActionName('create');
        }
        parent::preDispatch();

           /**
            * Parent check is complete, reset request action name to origional value
            */
           if ($action != $this->getRequest()->getActionName())
           {
            $this->getRequest()->setActionName($action);
           }
           if (!$this->getRequest()->isDispatched()) {
            return;
           }

        $mypattern = '/^(' . implode('|', $allActions) . ')/i';

        if (!preg_match($mypattern, $action)) {
            if (!$this->_getSession()->authenticate($this)) {
                $this->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);
            }
        } else {
            $this->_getSession()->setNoReferer(true);
        }



    }




    /* wholeSaler Login */
    public function vendorAction(){
            if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }
            $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Login-Required', 'true');
            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
            $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
            $this->renderLayout();

    }
/* whole Sales customer create login */
    public function vendorcreateAction()
    {
        if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*');
            return;
        }

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

        /**
     * Login post action
     */
    public function vendorloginPostAction()
    {
        if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

        if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
        $session = $this->_getSession();

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
            if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
                try {
                    $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
                    if ($session->getCustomer()->getIsJustConfirmed()) {
                        $this->_welcomeCustomer($session->getCustomer(), true);
                    }
                } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                    switch ($e->getCode()) {
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                            $value = $this->_getHelper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                            $message = $this->_getHelper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed. <a href="%s">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', $value);
                            break;
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                            break;
                        default:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                    }
                    $session->addError($message);
                    $session->setUsername($login['username']);
                     $this->_redirect('*/*/vendor');
                    return;
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    // Mage::logException($e); // PA DSS violation: this exception log can disclose customer password
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/vendor');
                    return;

                }
            } else {
                $session->addError($this->__('Login and password are required.'));
                     $this->_redirect('*/*/vendor');
                    return;

            }
        }
        //echo      'demo@gmail.com'.$session->getCustomerGroupId();
        //die();
        if($session->isLoggedIn()&& ($session->getCustomerGroupId()==4)){
            $this->gotorental();
            }
        elseif($session->isLoggedIn()&& ($session->getCustomerGroupId()==2)){
            $this->gotowholesale();
        }else{
        $this->_loginPostRedirect();
        }
    }



    /**
     * Create customer account action
     */
    public function vendorcreatePostAction()
    {
        /** @var $session Mage_Customer_Model_Session */
        $session = $this->_getSession();
        if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
        $session->setEscapeMessages(true); // prevent XSS injection in user input
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $errUrl = $this->_getUrl('*/*/vendorcreate', array('_secure' => true));
            $this->_redirectError($errUrl);
            return;
        }

        $customer = $this->_getCustomer();

         $customer->setGroupId($vendorCustomeraGroup);

        try {
            $errors = $this->_getCustomerErrors($customer);

            if (empty($errors)) {
                $customer->save();
                $this->_dispatchRegisterSuccess($customer);
                $this->_RestsuccessProcessRegistration($customer);
                return;
            } else {
                $this->_addSessionError($errors);
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            if ($e->getCode() === Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_EXISTS) {
                $url = $this->_getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword');
                $message = $this->__('There is already an account with this email address. If you are sure that it is your email address, <a href="%s">click here</a> to get your password and access your account.', $url);
                $session->setEscapeMessages(false);
            } else {
                $message = $e->getMessage();
            }
            $session->addError($message);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost())
                ->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot save the  Whole Saller customer.'));
        }
        $errUrl = $this->_getUrl('*/*/vendorcreate', array('_secure' => true));
        $this->_redirectError($errUrl);
    }
public function createPostAction()
    {
        echo 'here1234';exit;
        echo 'here123';exit;
        $errUrl = $this->_getUrl('*/*/create', array('_secure' => true));

        if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            $this->_redirectError($errUrl);
            return;
        }

        /** @var $session Mage_Customer_Model_Session */
        $session = $this->_getSession();
        if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

        if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $this->_redirectError($errUrl);
            return;
        }

        $customer = $this->_getCustomer();
/*$ek = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
print_r($ek);exit;*/
        try {
            $errors = $this->_getCustomerErrors($customer);

            if (empty($errors)) 
            {
                 if($this->getRequest()->getPost('group_id'))
                { 
                    $customer->setGroupId($this->getRequest()->getPost('group_id'));
                }                   
                else 
                {
                    $customer->getGroupId(); 
                }
                $customer->cleanPasswordsValidationData();
                $customer->save();
                $this->_dispatchRegisterSuccess($customer);
                $this->_successProcessRegistration($customer);
                return;
            } else {
                $this->_addSessionError($errors);
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            if ($e->getCode() === Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_EXISTS) {
                $url = $this->_getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword');
                $message = $this->__('There is already an account with this email address. If you are sure that it is your email address, <a href="%s">click here</a> to get your password and access your account.', $url);
            } else {
                $message = $this->_escapeHtml($e->getMessage());
            }
            $session->addError($message);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            $session->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot save the customer.'));
        }

        $this->_redirectError($errUrl);
    }

}
Helper class
app/code/local/Dev/Customcustomer/Helper/data.php
<?php
class Dev_Customcustomer_Helper_Data extends Mage_Customer_Helper_Data
{
      public function getWLoginPostUrl()
    {
        $params = array();
        if ($this->_getRequest()->getParam(self::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME)) {
            $params = array(
                self::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME => $this->_getRequest()->getParam(self::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME)
            );
        }
        return $this->_getUrl('customer/account/vendorloginPost', $params);
    }
    public function getwLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->_getUrl('customer/account/vendorlogin' ,$this->getLoginUrlParams());
    }
        public function getwRegisterUrl()
    {
        return $this->_getUrl('customer/account/vendorcreate' ,$this->getLoginUrlParams());
    }
    }
}
```

module XML
app/etc/modules/Dev_Customcustomer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--we need to enable this module as any other if-->
<!--you wish to do it as standalone module extension-->
<config>
<modules>
<Dev_Customcustomer>
<active>true</active>
<codepool>local</codepool>
</Dev_Customcustomer>
</modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue in  syntax in `Dev_Customcustomer.xml.`

The xml tag **codepool** should be **code`P`ool**.

codepool's P should be in  upper case .

Also suggestion to add depend at

**Dev_Customcustomer.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Dev_Customcustomer>
            <active>true</active>
            <!-- codepool's p should uppercase letter -->
            <codePool>local</codePool> 
            <!-- add depends module -->
            <depends>
                <Mage_Customer/>
            </depends>
        </Dev_Customcustomer>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Also, you can checkout this link [AccountController override not working on new Action and doing 302 redirection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76628/accountcontroller-override-not-working-on-new-action-and-doing-302-redirection)  redirection issue